# Overlapping geometry

Tags: geometry

I am modeling a tank in order to get used to the specifics of Blender (see attached image, although the texturing is not yet complete).

After I finished modeling, I noticed that every single object in the scene (turret, main body, wheels, screws etc.) is duplicated and overlapped many times! I had to manually select each object and delete all the overlapping duplicates. It took a lot of time and I have no idea what causes this. If I create a new object, at a certain point the program will duplicate it a number of times and overlap it on the existing geometry. I thought that maybe <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the reason, or the mirroring or rotating. But still, I tested it and this doesn't seems to be the answer. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've never noticed this problem of undesired copies, you must have accidentally hit Shift D or Alt D, or you've created another shortcut

Comment: Sounds like something simple and 'silly' in your workflow.  A very common one is the misapprehension that when you right-click after a generative move (Extrusion, Inset) you cancel the _generation_. In fact you just drop the new geometry in place, (overlapping). Could that be it?

Comment: So I found out what it was, quite a silly beginner mistake actually (similar to what Robin mentioned above). I have the axes turned off, so when I want to duplicate something and am in a hurry, sometimes I press an axis after Shift + D, then I realise it was another axis I actually needed, and in the process (I think I press right click involuntarily) the program creates a duplicate in place, overlapping with the original geometry.   Anyways, thank you for your answers.